# How do you say "If button is pressed, then do this" in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to say "if the thing that you are trying to press equal for is an integer, then do what i have, but if it is a string, then print either "cos(whatever number)", "tan(whatever number)", or "sin(whatever number)". Please help clarify how to do this. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

def btnPress(num):
    global result
    result = result+str(num)
    equation.set(result)

def equalPress():
    global result
    total = str(eval(result))
    equation.set(total)
    result = total

def clear():
    global result
    result = ""
    equation.set("")

result = ""
btnWidth = 5

equation = StringVar()
equation.set("Enter your equation.")
calculation = Label(root, textvariable = equation, width = btnWidth*4)
calculation.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)


Button0 = Button(root, text = "0", command=lambda:btnPress(0), width = btnWidth)
Button0.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

Button1 = Button(root, text = "1", command=lambda:btnPress(1), width = btnWidth)
Button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

Button2 = Button(root, text = "2", command=lambda:btnPress(2), width = btnWidth)
Button2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

Button3 = Button(root, text = "3", command=lambda:btnPress(3), width = btnWidth)
Button3.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

Button4 = Button(root, text = "4", command=lambda:btnPress(4), width = btnWidth)
Button4.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

Button5 = Button(root, text = "5", command=lambda:btnPress(5), width = btnWidth)
Button5.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

Button6 = Button(root, text = "6", command=lambda:btnPress(6), width = btnWidth)
Button6.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

Button7 = Button(root, text = "7", command=lambda:btnPress(7), width = btnWidth)
Button7.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

Button8 = Button(root, text = "8", command=lambda:btnPress(8), width = btnWidth)
Button8.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

Button9 = Button(root, text = "9", command=lambda:btnPress(9), width = btnWidth)
Button9.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

Button10 = Button(root, text = "tan", command=lambda:btnPress("tan "), width = btnWidth)
Button10.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

Button11 = Button(root, text = "sin", command=lambda:btnPress("sin "), width = btnWidth)
Button11.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

Button12 = Button(root, text = "cos", command=lambda:btnPress("cos "), width = btnWidth)
Button12.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

plus = Button(root, text = "+", command = lambda:btnPress("+"), width = btnWidth)
plus.grid(row = 1, column = 4)
plus = Button(root, text = "-", command = lambda:btnPress("-"), width = btnWidth)
plus.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
plus = Button(root, text = "*", command = lambda:btnPress("*"), width = btnWidth)
plus.grid(row = 3, column = 4)
plus = Button(root, text = "/", command = lambda:btnPress("/"), width = btnWidth)
plus.grid(row = 4, column = 4)
plus = Button(root, text = ".", command = lambda:btnPress("."), width = btnWidth)
plus.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

if  == 
    equal = Button(root, text = "=", command = equalPress, width = btnWidth)
    equal.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
equal = Button(root, text = "C", command = clear, width = btnWidth)
equal.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `if num == '=':`? What's the problem here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Please elaborate

Comment: I'm asking *you* to elaborate! `btnPress` takes a single argument `num`, so why don't you just check if that's equal to e.g. `'tan '`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't trying to be sarcastic in any way, and am not now. I'm really extremely sorry, but can tell that your help is useful, but I don't get what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: So you would put e.g. `if num == 'tan ': tan(result)` into `btnPress`. *"if the thing that you are trying to press equal for is an integer"* would be `if isinstance(num, int):`, but that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for the contents of `num`:

```
def btnPress(num):
    global result
    if num == "tan ":
        result = tan(float(result))
    elif num == "cos ":
        result = tan(float(result))
    ...
    else:
        result = result+str(num)
```